# How to implement closeAutocomplete method in ng4-geoautocompelete

Tags: angular, typescript, google-geolocation, google-location-services

I am using ng4-autocomplete component inside my custom component and I want to detect the change when the autocomplete dropdown closes. Can you please let me know how do you implement "closeAutocomplete" method?

This is my location.component.html

```
<ng4geo-autocomplete (click)="showAutocomplete()"
                     [userSettings]="location"
                     (componentCallback)="componentCallback123($event)" placeholder=""
                     (closeAutocomplete)="closeAutocomplete($event)"
>
</ng4geo-autocomplete>
```

and the following is the location.component.ts file.

```
import {Component, EventEmitter, Input, OnChanges, OnInit, Output, SimpleChanges} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'mitra-location',
    templateUrl: './location.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./location.component.scss']
})
export class LocationComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input('location') location = '';

    @Output('callback') callback = new EventEmitter<any>();

    locationElem;

    ngOnInit() {
        this.locationElem = document.getElementById('geo-location');
    }

    closeAutocomplete(event) {
        // Here i want to get this event
    }
}
```

[This](https://tanoy009.github.io/ng4-geoautocomplete/docs/components/AutoCompleteComponent.html) is the documentation link for this component.

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Does this help? https://github.com/tanoy009/ng4-geoautocomplete/blob/3d44fdf9abde32052d2e39a8d59d670b200c887d/src/auto-complete.component.ts#L391-L396

Comment: @hellow isn't that the source code for this package? how should I use this method in my own component?

Comment: Not sure. That's why I asked if it does help ;) I don't have any clue of ng4 so far

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the [documentation](https://tanoy009.github.io/ng4-geoautocomplete/docs/components/AutoCompleteComponent.html), there is no `closeAutocomplete()` **Output** defined on the `ng4geo-autocomplete` component.

The only Output defined is `componentCallback` which you have called correctly. You cannot call `closeAutocomplete` like that on the component, since it's not an Output property of the component.

Comment: Yeah, I know. 
That is my question, that how should I use the "closeAutocomplete" method then?

Comment: You cannot. Unless you modify the source code to make it as an Output yourself.

Comment: Then I am just curious, why does this public method "closeAutocomplete()" exist in there?

Comment: Because it is being used on an event binding in the template of the component. Check line 278 of the code here - https://github.com/tanoy009/ng4-geoautocomplete/blob/3d44fdf9abde32052d2e39a8d59d670b200c887d/src/auto-complete.component.ts#L278